# How to ensure exactly once semantics while processing kafka messages in Apache Storm

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-storm

I needed exactly once delivery in my app. I explored kafka and realised that to have message produced exactly once, I have to set `idempotence=true` in producer config. This also sets `acks=all`, making producer resend messages till all replicas have committed it. To ensure that consumer does not do duplicate processing or leave any message unprocessed, it is advised to commit the processing output and offset to external database in same database transaction, so that either both of them will be persisted or none avoiding duplicate and no processing.

In consumer, message is left processed if consumer first commits it but fails before processing it and message is processed more than once if consumers first processes it but fails before committing it.

**Q1.** Now I was guessing how can I imitate the same with Apache Storm. I guess exactly once production of message can be ensured by setting `idemptence=true` in `KafkaBolt`. Am I right?

I was guessing how I can ensure missed and duplicate message processing in Storm.  For example, [this doc page](https://storm.apache.org/releases/2.0.0/Guaranteeing-message-processing.html) says if I anchor a tuple (by passing it as first parameter to `OutputCollector.emit()`) and then pass the tuple to `OutputCollector.ack()` or `OutputCollector.fail()`, Storm will ensure data loss. This is what it exactly says:

> Now that you understand the reliability algorithm, let's go over all the failure cases and see how in each case Storm avoids data loss:
>
> - **A tuple isn't acked because the task died:** In this case the spout tuple ids at the root of the trees for the failed tuple will time out and be replayed.
> - **Acker task dies:** In this case all the spout tuples the acker was tracking will time out and be replayed.
> - **Spout task dies:** In this case the source that the spout talks to is responsible for replaying the messages. For example, queues like Kestrel and RabbitMQ will place all pending messages back on the queue when a client disconnects.

**Q2.** I guess this ensures that message is not left unprocessed, but does not avoid duplicate processing of messages. Am I correct with this? Also is there anything else that Storm offers to ensure exactly once semantics like kafka that I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

Regarding Q1: Yes, you can get the same behavior from the `KafkaBolt` by setting that property, the KafkaBolt simply wraps a `KafkaProducer`.

Regarding semantics on the consuming side, you have the same options with Storm as you do with Kafka. When you read a message from Kafka, you can choose to commit before or after you do your processing (e.g. write to a database). If you do it before, and the program crashes, you will lose the message. Let's call this `at-most-once processing`. If you do it after, you risk processing the same message twice if the program crashes after the processing but before the commit, called `at-least-once processing`.

So, regarding Q2: Yes, using anchored tuples and acking will provide you with `at-least-once` semantics. Not using anchored tuple would give you `at-most-once`.

Yes, there is something else Storm offers to ensure exactly once semantics called Trident, but it requires you to write your topology differently, and your data store has to be adapted to it so message deduplication can happen. See the documentation at https://storm.apache.org/releases/2.0.0/Trident-tutorial.html.

Also just to caution you: When documentation for Storm (or Kafka) talk about exactly-once semantics, there are some assumptions made about what kind of processing you'll do. For example, when Storm's Trident docs talk about exactly-once, there's an assumption that you'll adapt your database so you can decide when given a message whether it has already been stored. When Kafka's documentation talks about exactly-once, the assumption is that your processing will be reading from Kafka, doing some computation (most likely with no side effects) and writing back to Kafka.

This is just to say that for some types of processing, you may still need to pick between `at-least-once` and `at-most-once`. If you can make your processing idempotent, `at-least-once` is a good option.

Finally if your processing fits the "read from Kafka, do computation, write to Kafka" model, you can likely get nicer semantics out of Kafka Streams than Storm, as Storm can't provide the exactly-once semantics Kafka can provide in that case.